# Bootstrap affix navbar glitchy on mobile?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, affix

I set up an affixed navbar with an offset of 100 px (my header height) with bootstrap and I modified the .navbar.affix css giving it a -100px top margin in order to have it stick to the top.

Well, it works perfectly on PC, but when I preview my website on mobile the navbar is glitchy.

It works, but when I scroll over the 100px offset it remains invisible until I lift my finger, then it appears at the top. 
I didn't post any code because you would have to reproduce it on a mobile device (copying html, css, js, hosting it, etc), but do you know if this is a known issue?

If it is ok, otherwise I'm doing something wrong

EDIT:
HTML

```
 <body>
    <header class="header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <center> <h1>My header</h1></center></div>                  
                      </div>
           </div>
            </header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"></a>
</div>
<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li ><a href="index.php">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li class="dropdown active">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu inverse-dropdown">
        <li class="active"><a href="about.php">Su di Noi</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">Element</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Element</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Element</a></li>
      </ul>            
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropwdown<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu inverse-dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Element</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">Element</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Element</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Element</a></li>
      </ul>            
    </li>
   <li><a href="#">Element</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Element</a></li>
    </ul>
      </div>
</div>
</nav>
  <div>
 <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
            <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
            <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
            <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
            <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
            <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
            <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
            <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
            <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
       <h1>TEXT HERE TO ENABLE SCROLLING</h1>
```

CSS

```
.header {
height: 100px;
}

.navbar.affix {
width: 100%;
margin-top: -100px;
}
```

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lq94wLbj/

Comment: Please add a complete, working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) Please see [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: @vanburen added, but as I said, it works perfectly from a PC browser, I have problems when browsing with a mobile device